# Create directory using filenames and move the files to its repective folder

Tags: files, directory, rename

I have a folder with around 150 text files. I would like to create folders in the name of the 150 files. After that I would like the text file to be moved to its respective folder.

Example names of the files inside myfolder directory:

```
~/myfolder/
       |______ ajhaslf.txt
       |______ oiueed.txt
       |______ dsflije.txt
```

How I would like my new structure to be:

```
~/myfolder/
       |______ ajhaslf
                   |____ajhaslf.txt
       |______ oiueed
                   |____oiueed.txt
       |______ dsflije
                   |____dsflije.txt
```

Of course creating directory with the filenames is not a problem for me with `mkdir`.

Comment: `cd` into your folder and: `for file in *.txt; do mkdir -- "${file%.txt}"; mv -- "$file" "${file%.txt}"; done`

Comment: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘GmZzz3StdPk.txt’: File exists

Comment: Are you sure you copied the line I gave (especially the `"${file%.txt}"`? What is your shell?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Yes, I copied the same thing and tried. My shell is bash

Comment: Do you have a file named `GmZzz3StdPk.txt.txt`?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf why not make that into an answer? biobudhan that should work, which version of bash is this? What operating system?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: I have a file named GmZzz3StdPk.txt not GmZzz3StdPk.txt.txt

Answer (score 10):

[@gniourf_gniourf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139518/create-directory-using-filenames-and-move-the-files-to-its-repective-folder/139520#comment224906_139518) has the right idea:

```
set -o errexit -o nounset
cd ~/myfolder
for file in *.txt
do
    dir="${file%.txt}"
    mkdir -- "$dir"
    mv -- "$file" "$dir"
done
```

This should be POSIX compliant. It is *not* re-entrant. It will *not* work if you have any two files named `something.txt` and `something.txt.txt`.

Comment: Maybe `mkdir -- "$dir" && mv -- "$file" "$dir"` to make sure we don't execute uncontrolled commands. Otherwise it's perfect. `:D`. Not sure though about the `something.txt.txt` thing; that was my first thought but now I believe that `something.txt` would come before `something.txt.txt` in the expansion of `*.txt`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf `errexit` to the rescue. For the duplicate suffix, `cannot create directory GmZzz3StdPk.txt` definitely means that it fails when processing `GmZzz3StdPk.txt.txt`, independently of the files' sequence in the output.

Comment: And how about `shopt -s nullglob` too, to be sure we're on the safe side? `:D`.

Comment: That depends on whether there being no matching files is an error or not.

Comment: So then `shopt -s failglob`?

Comment: From OP's comment: _@gniourf_gniourf: Yes, I copied the same thing and tried. My shell is bash_.

Comment: I mean it's up to the user (independently of this question) whether to `shopt -s nullglob` or `shopt -s failglob`.

Comment: Works!! and you just solved my pain of media files management!!